# Toast showing error

Tags: angularjs

I want to show toast in my app. For that I used:

```
mySchoolApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http,$location, $mdToast) {
this.loginForm = function() {

        let uname = this.inputData.username;
        let pass= this.inputData.password;
            if (pass === 123456) {
                sessionStorage.setItem("userID", '123456');
                window.location.href = '#dashboard';

            } else {
                $mdToast.show(
  $mdToast.simple()
    .textContent('Either email or password is incorrect!')
    .position("top right")
    .hideDelay(3000)
);

            }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //error msgs
        })
    }
}]);
```

But while running my app,its showing the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

How to sort this issue in my app?

Comment: Can you share a fiddle/plunker for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the toast service from your controller's dependency injection array:

```
mySchoolApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$mdToast', function($scope, $http,$location, $mdToast) ......
```